# How to find $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ for Functions of the form $f(x,y,z(y))$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, chain-rule

This is the first time I'm using math.stackexchange. Please excuse me and correct me if I'm not doing things in the right format.

So my question is this: given a function of the form $f(x,y,z(y))$, and suppose we want to find $\frac{∂}{∂y} f(x,y,z(y))$. Then by the Chain Rule, we would have something like this

$$\frac{∂f}{∂y} = \frac{∂f}{∂y} + \frac{∂f}{∂z}\frac{dz}{dy}.$$

But this notation is really confusing since the two $\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ do not mean the same thing. Am I doing this correctly, or is there any better notation to clarify this expression? I would be much appreciated if someone could shed some light on me.

Comment: But f is a multi-variable function of x, y , so we have to use the partial derivative instead of a single derivative.

Comment: Of course, but you have to not confuse the function $f(x,y,z)$ and the function $F(x,y)=f(x,y,z(y))$ The first is a function of three variables $x,y,z$ while the second is a function of two variables $x,y$. Poeple familiar with multi variables calculus loosely use a common symbol for both without making mistake. For one not yet familiar with these symbolism it is suggested to use different symbols : $$∂F/∂y = ∂f/∂y + (∂f/∂z)(dz/dy)$$

Comment: @JJacquelin : You should make your comment into an answer.

Comment: Using the same name for different functions is a *bad idea*.

Comment: @JJacquelin : Somehow your first comment makes more sense to me. In your first comment, does $df/dy$ represents a total derivative? I feel like I mix up the concept of total derivative with a single derivative.

Comment: I delete my first comment because it confuses you.

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse the function $f(x,y,z)$ and the function $F(x,y)=f(x,y,z(y))$.

The first is a function of three variables $x,y,z$ while the second is a function of two variables $x,y$.

People familiar with multi variables calculus loosely use a common symbol for both without making mistake. For one not yet familiar with these symbolism it is suggested to use different symbols : 
$$\frac{∂F}{∂y}=\frac{∂f}{∂y}+\frac{∂f}{∂z}\:\frac{dz}{dy}$$

Comment: OK, I think I got it. Usually, this wouldn't confuse me if the function is in the form of $f(x(u,v), y(u,v))$, even though $f(x(u,v), y(u,v))$ really means $F(u,v)$. But I'm still really curious about your first comment. In your first comment, you use $df/dy$. I feel like this is a total derivative, and I think $df/dy=∂F/∂y$, right?

Comment: No, this is not the total derivative except if $x$ is considered as a constant parameter, not a variable.  The correct writing is  $$df=(∂f/∂x)dx+( (∂f/∂y) +(∂f/∂z)(dz/dy))dy$$.

Comment: OK, I see. So the $\frac{df}{dy}$ you use in your first comment is just your convention of notation. I wonder if this a common practice, because rewriting $f(x,y,z(y))=F(x,y)$ and $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ is inconvenient.